# how to register django_migrations table to django-admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-migrations

how to add or register django_migrations table or MigrationRecorder model to django-admin panel?

I have tried the following solutions, but to no avail!

```py
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(MigrationRecorder)
```

```py
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(MigrationRecorder.Migration)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django version: 3.7

1. add 'django.db.migrations' to installed_app in settings.py
2. add below code to admin.py

```html
from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(MigrationRecorder.Migration)
```

Answer (score 0):

The migration class model is storing at `MigrationRecorder.Migration._migration_class`, so probably need to register this class:

```py
from django.db.migrations.recorder MigrationRecorder
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(MigrationRecorder.Migration._migration_class)
```

But very strange, if the user changes a value in this table, it's the whole app that can be broken

Comment: By registering your suggested item, I get this error: AttributeError: type object 'Migration' has no attribute 'Migration'.
MigrationRecorder.Migration is a class and does not have Migration Attribute.

Comment: I made an error, the name of class is `_migration_class`, I fix my post

Comment: same error. AttributeError: type object 'Migration' has no attribute '_migration_class'

Comment: Maybe you need to register in the ready app function? Question, why do you want to let the user change the value of this table?

Comment: I have some "data migration" files that I want to remove them from the migrations directory and from the database. For ease of work, I don't want to do this by running a query in the database or django-shell everytime, but I want to do it by using django-admin.

Comment: Remove a row in the Migration table in db does not remove the file in the migrations directory and at the restart of your application, Django could relaunch this migration a second time. Moreover, migrations will be broken if there are migrations after your data migration file you want to remove.  Probably better to think about a solution to make data migrations outside of the Migration model?
In both cases, I think, you have to test with admin action for customizing what you want to 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: Well, I know that deleting the record in Migration table does not delete the corresponding migration.py file. As I mentioned in the previous comment, I'm just looking for a way to not delete the relevant record by query or django-shell. And one more thing, as long as I can't see the Migration table in the admin panel, there is no point in writing the action function... Anyway, thanks for your time.